# How to find a minimum and maximum values from NSArray having a custom class objects?

Tags: objective-c, filter, nsarray, max, min

I have an `NSArray` with custom class objects having a `NSNumber`property. I am trying to fetch a minimum & maximum values from the array. So this is my code:

```
MyClass *minObj = [filteredArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self.height"];
MyClass *maxObj = [filteredArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self.height"];
```

This works and I could get a min and max values but is of `NSNumber` type. So `minObj` and `maxObj` will be of a number and not of `MyClass` type.

Is there a good way to find out the same and get the `MyClass` instead of `NSNumber`?

P.S. There can be more than one same values which can be minimum or maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write code to do it. For example (typed directly into answer, expect minor typos):

```
MyObj *minObj = filteredArray[0];
for(MyObj *candidate in filteredArray)
   if([candidate.height compare:minObj.height] == NSOrderedDescending)
      minObj = candidate;
```

You can of course find both min and max using a single pass over your array.

HTH

Comment: Should, `filteredArray` is requires to be sorted?

Comment: Read the code, what is the algorithm it uses (how does it work)? Does it only work if the array is sorted? You will appreciate the answer better if you work it out yourself.